# Can't get correct characters when retrieving JSON from JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I created a JSP page that contains a `JSON object` created using `taglib-json` which contains a set of Arabic words and phrases, but when I retrieve it using `ajax` the Arabic words are not correct or properly encoded.

I already set all my JSP page encoding as `UTF-8` in my `web.xml`.

Here is my JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; 
 charset=UTF=8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<json:object>
    <json:property name="title" value="${text['tile']}"/>
    <json:property name="desc" value="${text['desc']}"/>
</json:object>
```

`Ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "....",
      dataType: "json"
}).done(function( res ) {
     console.log(res);
});
```

Arabic words are retrieved from a `ResourceBundle`.

Console Result:

```
{
   "title": "Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø·Ø§Ù„Ø¨",
   "desc": "Ø±Ù‚Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø·Ø§Ù‚Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø®ØµÙŠØ© Ù„Ù„Ø·Ø§Ù„Ø¨"
}
```

When I open the page directly, it shows the Arabic words correctly.

Comment: @amy what is the difference except the last space after UTF-8"?

Comment: `charset=UTF=8` should be `charset=UTF-8` (but I don't know if it fixes your problem)

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thanks man, it fixed the problem, ugh I feel so stupid.